# Associate overlapping sectors from one layer to another - and at what percent

Tags: geography

Good morning,

I have 2 maps of my country in the form of 2 geojsons, but with 2 different subdivisions of the country into polygons:
1- Sectors which have no geographical meaning in terms of common geographical boundaries
2- Regions (which are common geographical boundaries)

I have data for both geographical units (sectors and regions) with no direct link between them.

There is a many-to-many correspondence between sectors and regions, meaning that sectors can encompass regions, or cut through them; and regions could also encompass sectors or cut through them.

I would like an algorithm/software that yields the correspondences between sector(s) and region(s). Maybe in this form, or maybe through a matrix regions vs. sectors, with percentages at the intersections, and each row and column accounting for 100%.

Sector_0 : 100% (of its surface) in Region_0

Sector_1 : 60% in Region_1; 25% in Region_2; 15% in Region_0...

Sector_2 : 40% in Region_1; 10% in Region_2; 50% in Region_4...
...

and similarly:

Region_0 : X% (of its surface) is in Sector_0; Y% in Sector_1;...

Region_1 : X% in Sector_1; Y% in Sector_2;...

...

I have searched the internet but I might use the wrong keywords.

Do you know any software that could do it? Or any (Python preferred) algorithm that might do the trick as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://mentin.medium.com/mapping-statistics-between-different-spatial-hierarchies-9625a7064a15

Comment: This might be it ! i am not very comfortable with SQL language as presented but the end result looks like it. I will investigate the code. Thanks so much for your answer!